# How to emulate touchscreen style scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch

I want to try to emulate the touch scroll gestures found on touchscreen devices for PC/Mac. However, I don't want to disable the scrollwheel. I would like to hide the scrollbar though.

Does anyone know any demos/code out there that attempts to do this?

Comment: might be helpful if you googled scrolling physics.

Comment: Emulate touchscreen using the mouse ?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858333/is-there-an-easy-way-to-do-click-and-drag-scrolling-in-text-frames

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962082/ipad-iphone-like-scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On certain browsers<sup>1</sup>, hiding the main scrollbar is impossible. However, the general method is this:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ6k2/), and [here's a demo with the scrollwheel handled.](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ6k2/3/)

---

<sup>1</sup> i.e. IE8 and lower.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-the-scroll-wheel

Comment: This will disable the scroll-wheel functionality as well.

Comment: right, I am just pointing out that your answer is not complete. :)

Comment: @DeviantSeev: Does for me, which version? Anyway, just an example.

Comment: Demo with scroll wheel did not work for me with latest version of Chrome.

Comment: @DeviantSeev: Which latest version? Mainstream, beta, dev, or nightly?

Answer (score 0):

In Webkit-based browsers (e.g., Chrome), you can use [`::-webkit-scrollbar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

In Firefox, you can use [`scrollbar-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width):

```
* {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```